# Logistic Regression is all about stats?

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression

Following the iris DataSets exemples , I tried to make my first Logistic Regression. My X is the number of words in a sentence and I would like (with the help of other parameters but later) to find the probability that a sentence have to have a specific term ( named entities ).

So in my stats I have some sentences with only 15 words that have it or sentences with 80 words that haven't. With only this parameter , it seems to be a little bit random. Not a real rule.

Am I doing something wrong ? Or We can justify these bad results only by the "not good enough" parameter ? 
All of this , makes me think that logistic regression is only stats (I think it's true actually, but I'm lost now )

That's why in my Logistic Regression , I find out a

```
log_reg.score(X,y) = 0.7666
```

(didn't understand very well what it means )

and with this :

```
X_new = np.linspace(20, 80,150).reshape(150,1)  #150 Sentences between 20 and 80 words 
y_proba = log_reg.predict_proba(X_new)
decision_boundary = X_new[y_proba[:, 1] >= 0.5][0]
```

I got  [68.32214765] for decision boundary with a max % of  0.57 ...

Am I doing something wrong ? Or We can justify these bad results only by the "not good enough" parameter ?

All of this , makes me think that logistic regression is only stats (I think it's true actually, but I'm lost now )

How can I be sure that a logistic regression woks well ?

Comment: I think you are asking several questions and they are more about assessing if a machine learning/statistical model is "working" or not. Which might be better on another Stack Exchange site. In general though, have some training data and try your model out on unseen test data as a first step.

Comment: By generating X_new , I'm doing this first step. But  I just wanna know if it can be "normal" or "usual" to get low score like this one, or if not , what am I doign wrong ?